# Update: Combining DistributionChart and BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics, distributions, charts

## Goal

The goal is to merge the default styles of a few different charts; namely, to have a chart that:

- has the key components of `BoxWhiskerChart`
- the outline of the `DistributionChart`'s `ChartElementFunction`$\rightarrow$`SmoothDensity`
- has the points of the `DistributionChart` `ChartElementFunction`$\rightarrow$`PointDensity`

Further, I would like to have the ability to:

- color the points based on other data
- add `Callout`s to specified points.

Final outcome addressing all the requirements above should look like:

[image]

## Example

Sample data

```
data = {RandomInteger[100, 30], RandomInteger[100, 30]};
```

Individual chart elements

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data]
DistributionChart[data]
DistributionChart[data, ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity"]
```

External data for color:

```
With[{perm=Permute[data[[1]]]}, class1 = perm[[1;;Floor@Length@perm/2]]; class2 = perm[[Floor@Length@perm/2+1;;]]]
```

Such that points belonging to class1 are one color and class2 are another.

[image]

Here is an image showing the transformations I would like to make:

[image]

---

---

## Understanding @kglr's code

Kudos to @kglr for being able to do this, but I have very little idea of what is going on in the code. Let's break it down line, by line, and perhaps tweak this a bit for re-use :)

---

For two dimensional charts, `ChartElementFunction` passes `region`, `values` and `metadata` to the function. So let's start by changing the function definition to be more readable:

```
Options[BoxWhiskerDistributionChart] = {"InternalOpacity" -> 0.7};

BoxWhiskerDistributionChart[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, values_,metadata_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[
{parameters = {{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, values, metadata}},
{    
(*block of code*)
}
]
```

Yes the definition is longer, but it is more readable to people (like me) who do not dabble with customizing graphic often. The local variable `parameters` will take the place of `##`.

---

Inside the block of code, the first two lines are:

```
EdgeForm[{Thick, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}],
FaceForm[Opacity[.7, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]],
```

I do not understand why we have to call the Charting` context... I believe, we could tweak this to be:

```
EdgeForm[Thick],
FaceForm[Opacity[OptionValue["InternalOpacity"]]],
```

---

Next we have the first `With` block:

```
With[
 {dd = #2},
 Normal[ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][##]] /. 
  GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> 
   Polygon[DeleteCases[
     AffineTransform[tr]@
      x, {_, _?((# < Quantile[dd, .25] || # > Quantile[dd, .75]) &)}],
     y]
 ]
```

First we will apply some changes in variables - according to our new function definition -  remove some unneeded code, and rename other variables.

```
ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][parameters] /. 
  GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], transformation_] :> 
   Polygon[DeleteCases[
     AffineTransform[transformation_]@
      x, {_, _?((# < Quantile[values, .25] || # > Quantile[values, .75]) &)}],
     y]
```

The first line of this chuck of code:

```
ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][parameters]
```

Is just the operator form of applying the `"SmoothDensity"` ChartElementFunction that we want to our current parameter. The `Normal` was not needed.

Because our new function definition gives us access to the values, we can remove the `With` block.

My remaining questions on this chuck of the code are as follows:

1. You have an internally defined function with a delayed rule (see below). What is the transformation function. Where did it come from?

   GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> etc

2.) I can see what this does (selects only the data within the .25=.75 quantiles), but I have no idea how:

```
AffineTransform[transformation_]@x, {_, _?((# < Quantile[values, .25] || # > Quantile[values, .75]) &)}],y]
```

So we apply the mysterious transformation to only the x values for some reason, then pattern match for any pair such that the y value falls in the right quantile.

This entire line has to have a  cleaner way of being written (e.g. write out the variables for y_ _ _, etc. I just don't know what that is...

---

The next line is straight forward. Nothing to change.

---

Now we add the points with this chuck:

```
ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", 
   "PointStyle" -> PointSize[Medium]][##] /. 
 GraphicsGroup[{x_, y__}] :> ({y} /. 
    Point[p_] :> (({If[MemberQ[class, #[[2]]], col], Point[{#}]} & /@ 
        p)))
```

Again we can rewrite parts of it:

```
ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", 
   "PointStyle" -> PointSize[Medium]][parameters] /. 
 GraphicsGroup[{x_, y__}] :> ({y} /. 
    Point[p_] :> (({If[MemberQ[class, #[[2]]], col], Point[{#}]} & /@ 
        p)))
```

This code isolates which points are of interest and changes their color. However I do not find this code straight forward with two delayed rules and replacement.

So if someone can explain this to me? All of it.

---

The next two lines, are called to overwrite the "PointDensity" Edge and Face Forms.

While I see that it works. Why do we have to recall them? Can't we just assign them prior to PointDensity and only take the Points?

---

and the last line is best summed up by @kglr:

Finally, System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot[] produces the basic box-whisker graphics objects in BoxWhiskerChart, and the modification I made is to add the directives EdgeForm[] and FaceForm[]

Although I do not know why we have to call that context...
Is there a way to do this without getting into contexts?

---

---

## Ideal

The following code outlines a more ideal solution, allowing for users to alter various parameters, change the cutoff, and specify points to highlight via the corresponding option.

This does not work. I think it either has something to do with `Module`, or the explicit use of the parameters...

```
Options[BoxWhiskerDistributionChart] = {"InternalOpacity" -> 0.7, 
   "PointsToHighlight" -> {}, "PointToHighlightColor" -> Black, 
   "UpperCutoff" -> .75, "LowerCutoff" -> .25, 
   "EdgeColor" -> Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"] };
BoxWhiskerDistributionChart[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, values_,
   metadata_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {chartParameters = {{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, values, metadata}},
  {

     (*Give boxes thick edges with their respective color*)

     EdgeForm[{Thick, OptionValue["EdgeColor"]}],
     (*Alter boxes internal opacity with their respective color*)

      FaceForm[
      Opacity[OptionValue["InternalOpacity"], 
       Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]],

     (*Use smooth density to change box shape, 
     with given quantile cutoffs*)

     ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][chartParameters] /. 
      GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], transformation_] :> 
       Polygon[
        DeleteCases[
         AffineTransform[transformation]@
          x, {_, _?((# < 
                Quantile[values, OptionValue["LowerCutoff"]] || # > 
                Quantile[values, OptionValue["UpperCutoff"]]) &)}], y],
     Opacity[1],

     (*Color points also foudn in the PointsToHighlight option*)

     ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", 
        "PointStyle" -> PointSize[Medium]][chartParameters] /. 
      GraphicsGroup[{x_, y__}] :> ({y} /. 
         Point[p_] :> (({If[
                MemberQ[OptionValue["PointsToHighlight"], #[[2]]], 
                OptionValue["PointToHighlightColor"]], Point[{#}]} & /@
              p))),

     (*Remove the default BoxWhiskerChart EdgeForm*)
     EdgeForm[],
     (*Remove the default BoxWhiskerChart FaceForm*)
     FaceForm[],
     (*Produce the plot*)

     System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot[][chartParameters]
     } &;
  ]
```

Comment: I have sadly currently no time but i brainstormed something for you which should be a helpful start. `Graphics[Cases[Level[DistributionChart[data],-1],GeometricTransformationBox[PolygonBox[_],___]],AspectRatio->1]`

Comment: SumNeuron, I cut and pasted the picture that summarizes your requirements nicely in the Goal section. If you you don't like it please revert to the previous edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Final Update:** Adding `Callout`s to special points

```
ClearAll[leaderSizeF, calloutF, densityCalloutWhiskerF]
leaderSizeF[bx_] := Switch[Sign[(# - Mean /@ bx)], 
  {1, 1} | {0, 0} |{1, 0} | {0, 1}, {{40, 45 Degree, 0}, {40, 0 Degree}}, 
  {1, -1} | {0, -1}, {{40, 315 Degree, 0}, {40, 0 Degree}},
  {-1, 1} | {-1, 0}, {{40, 135 Degree, 0}, {40, 180 Degree}}, 
  {-1, -1}, {{40, 225 Degree, 0}, {40, 180 Degree}}] &

calloutF[label_ : "Special Point", labelcol_ : Black, fontsize_ : 12, col_ : Red][bx_] := 
 Function[p, Callout[p, Style[ label, fontsize, Bold, labelcol], 
   Appearance -> "Leader", LeaderSize -> (leaderSizeF[bx][p]), 
   CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", "CalloutStyle" -> col]]

densityCalloutWhiskerF[label_:"Special Point", labelcol_:Black, 
      fontsize_:12, col_:Red][class1_ : {}, class2_ : {}, from_ : .25, 
      to_ : .75, opacity_ : .7, pointstyle_ : PointSize[Medium], 
      highlightstyle_ : Directive[PointSize[Large], Black]] := 
    Module[{xx = (SeedRandom[123]; RandomReal[#[[1]], Length@class2]),
      color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"],
      boxrange = {Min[#2], Quantile[#2, from], Median[#2], Quantile[#2, to], Max[#2]}, 
      thresholdrule = GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> 
        Polygon[Select[AffineTransform[tr]@x, 
          Function[z, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[Quantile[#2, {from, to}]], z[[2]]]]], y]},
      Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoxRange"] = boxrange; 
   {EdgeForm[{Thick, color}], FaceForm[Opacity[opacity, color]], 
    ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][##] /. thresholdrule,
    EdgeForm[], FaceForm[],  ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##],
    Opacity[1],  ListPlot[ Transpose[{RandomReal[#[[1]], Length@#2], #2}] /. 
       {p : {_, Alternatives @@ class1} :> Style[p, highlightstyle] }, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker[color], pointstyle]][[1]], 
    ListPlot[calloutF[label, labelcol, fontsize, col][#] /@ 
      Transpose[{xx, class2}]][[1]] /. Rotate[x_, 0.] :> x}] &;
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[100, 100];
class1 = RandomSample[data, Length[data]/4];
class2 = RandomSample[class1, 10];
class1 = Complement[class1, class2];

BoxWhiskerChart[ data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
  ImageSize -> 700, ChartStyle -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ChartElementFunction -> densityCalloutWhiskerF[][class1, class2, .3, .7, .5, 
   PointSize[Medium], Directive[PointSize[.007], Green]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Making the hard coded parameters in the original answer optional arguments with default values:

```
ClearAll[densityWhiskerF]
densityWhiskerF[class_: {}, from_: .25, to_: .75, opacity_: .7,
    pointstyle_: PointSize[Medium], 
    highlightstyle_: Directive[PointSize[Large], Black]] := 
  Module[{color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"],
     boxrange = {Min[#2], Quantile[#2, from], Median[#2], Quantile[#2, to], Max[#2]},
     thresholdrule = GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> 
       Polygon[Select[AffineTransform[tr]@x, 
         Function[z, Quantile[#2, from] <= z[[2]] <= Quantile[#2, to]]], y],
     highlightrule = Point[p_] :> ({If[MemberQ[class, f2@#], highlightstyle], 
       Point[{#}]} & /@ p)}, 
    Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoxRange"] = boxrange;
    {EdgeForm[{Thick, color}], FaceForm[Opacity[opacity, color]], 
      ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][##] /. thresholdrule,
     Opacity[1], ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity",
          "PointStyle" -> pointstyle][##] /. highlightrule, 
     EdgeForm[], FaceForm[], ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker"][##]}] &;
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[100, {10, 100}];
perm = RandomSample[data[[1]]];
class1 = perm[[1 ;; Floor@Length@perm/4]];

Legended[BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
   ImageSize -> 700, ChartStyle -> 24, ChartElementFunction -> densityWhiskerF[class1]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Directive[Black, PointSize[Large]]}, 
   {Style["Special points", 16, "Panel"]}], Above]]
```

[image]

With non-default values:

```
Legended[BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
   ChartStyle -> 24, ImageSize -> 700,
   ChartElementFunction ->  densityWhiskerF[class1, .4, .6, .8, 
     AbsolutePointSize[5], Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, 
    {Style["Special points", 16, "Panel"]}], Above]]
```

[image]

With default values of the arguments:

```
Legended[BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
  ChartStyle -> 24, ImageSize -> 700, ChartElementFunction -> densityWhiskerF[]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, 
  {Style["Special points", 16, "Panel"]}], Above]]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** With a few changes OP's *ideal* solution can be fixed to give the same result:

```
ClearAll[BoxWhiskerDistributionChart]
Options[BoxWhiskerDistributionChart] = {"InternalOpacity" -> 0.7, 
   "PointsToHighlight" -> {}, "PointToHighlightColor" -> Black, 
   "UpperCutoff" -> .75, "LowerCutoff" -> .25, 
   "EdgeColor" -> Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]};

BoxWhiskerDistributionChart[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, values_,
   metadata_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{chartParameters = Sequence[{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, values, metadata]}, 
 {(*Give boxes thick edges with their respective color*) 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, OptionValue["EdgeColor"]}],
  (*Alter boxes internal opacity with their respective color*)
   FaceForm[Opacity[OptionValue["InternalOpacity"], 
     Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]],
  (*Use smooth density to change box shape, with given quantile cutoffs*)
   ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][chartParameters] /. 
    GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], transformation_] :> 
     Polygon[DeleteCases[AffineTransform[transformation] @ x, 
      {_, _?((# < Quantile[values, OptionValue["LowerCutoff"]] || # > 
              Quantile[values, OptionValue["UpperCutoff"]]) &)}], y],       Opacity[1],
   (*Color points also foudn in the PointsToHighlight option*) 
    ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", "PointStyle" ->
     PointSize[Medium]][chartParameters] /. 
      GraphicsGroup[{x_, y__}] :> ({y} /. 
       Point[p_] :> (({If[MemberQ[OptionValue["PointsToHighlight"], #[[2]]], 
              OptionValue["PointToHighlightColor"]], Point[{#}]} & /@ p))),
   (*Remove the default BoxWhiskerChart EdgeForm*)
   EdgeForm[],
   (*Remove the default BoxWhiskerChart FaceForm*)
   FaceForm[],
  (*Produce the plot*)
   System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot[][chartParameters]}]
```

Example:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
 ChartStyle -> 24, ImageSize -> 700, ChartElementFunction -> 
  (BoxWhiskerDistributionChart[##, "PointsToHighlight" -> class1] &)]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to get almost all your requirements:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[class_, col_: Black] := {EdgeForm[{Thick, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}], 
     FaceForm[Opacity[.7, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]]], 
     With[{dd = #2}, Normal[ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][##]] /. 
       GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> 
        Polygon[DeleteCases[AffineTransform[tr]@x, {_, _?((# < Quantile[dd, .25] || # > 
                 Quantile[dd, .75]) &)}], y]], Opacity[1], 
     ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", "PointStyle" -> PointSize[Medium]][##] /. 
      GraphicsGroup[{x_, y__}] :> ({y} /. 
         Point[p_] :> (({If[MemberQ[class, #[[2]]], col], Point[{#}]} & /@ p))), 
     EdgeForm[], FaceForm[], System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot[][##]} &;

data = {RandomInteger[100, 100], RandomInteger[100, 100]};
With[{perm = RandomSample[data[[1]]]}, 
  class1 = perm[[1 ;; Floor@Length@perm/4]];
  class2 = perm[[Floor@Length@perm/4 + 1 ;;]]];

Legended[BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, 
  ChartStyle -> {Red, Blue}, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[class1]], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Black}, {"Special points"}], Above]]
```

[image: "Mathematica graphics"]

**Notes:**

The function `ceF` modifies and combines several built-in `ChartElementFunction`s to produce the desired graphics objects, Please see the docs on [ChartElementFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChartElementFunction.html).

`ChartElementDataFunction["PointDensity", "PointStyle" -> PointSize[Medium]]` is the full name of the function that produces the point density in `DistributionChart`; I modified it to remove the background density and to change the color of the special points.

Similarly, `ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"]` is the function that produces smooth density objects in `DistributionChart`. I post-processed the output of this function to remove the portions outside the range from .25th to .75th percentiles.

Finally, `` System`BarFunctionDump`boxplot[] `` produces the basic box-whisker graphics objects in `BoxWhiskerChart`, and the modification I made is to add the directives `EdgeForm[]` and `FaceForm[]` to effectively remove the box part of the box-whisker graphics object.

Comment: thanks for this useful answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the vote @ubpdqn.

Comment: @kglr Also thank you for this.  You use many aspects that I am very unfamiliar with, e.g. ``Charting`ChartStyleInformation`` (what is the tick doing?).  I know this will take a substantial bit of time, however I was hoping you might elucidated each step in making your function.

Comment: @SumNeuron, for the tick please see [tutorial/Contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html). I updated the post with some notes on how the function `ceF` is constructed. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kglr I am reading up on context and CEFs. However you do quite a lot rather quickly. What is the double slot `##`?  the `_?`?  What is the value that of `#2`? It isn't the second argument `col_`. I am sorry for asking so much, however I do really want to understand this. Could you possible make a concrete example showing how each transformation occurs?

Comment: From the`ChartElementFunction->f specifies that each chart element should be rendered with the graphics primitives given by f[region,values,metadata]`.  `##` stands for the arguments of the chart element function, it is a short hand for `Sequence[#1,#2,#3]`. So `#2` stands for the second argument, i.e., values. (see the [ChartElementFunction>> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) For `_?(..)` please see [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html)

Comment: You might want to play with various pieces to see how the modifications work: for example, try `dd= RandomReal[10,50]; aa=Normal[ChartElementDataFunction["SmoothDensity"][{{0,1},{0,10}},dd]` and `Graphics[aa, AspectRatio->1]` and `Graphics[aa /. 
  GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x_, y___], tr_] :> 
   Polygon[DeleteCases[
     AffineTransform[tr]@
      x, {_, _?((# < Quantile[dd, .25] || # > Quantile[dd, .75]) &)}],
     y], AspectRatio -> 1]`

Comment: @kglr I want to accept your answer, as it technically answers my question. It does combine the graph styles. However, it is written in a way that makes it un-editable to me because I simply have no idea what you are doing. Your comments show me how you make the outline of the charts, but the syntax of the code is not clear -- to me.  Thus I am highlight the parts I do not understand above.

Comment: Sorry to write this post as an answer post but my reputation is 45 and I need 50 to write it as a comment. Your custom functions are really impressive. I am using them a lot but would like to add something. I would like to color the points based on another variable. Let's say I have a two dimensions dataset {{x1,y1,}...{xn,yn}} and I would like to plot the distribution (boxwhiskerchart and point position) according to the xi values and the point color according to the yi values.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Porty, you can replace `ListPlot[Transpose[{RandomReal[#[[1]], 
      Length@#2], #2}] /. {p : {_, Alternatives @@ class1} :> 
     Style[p, highlightstyle]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Darker[color], pointstyle]][[1]]` with `ListPlot[ List/@Transpose[{RandomReal[#[[1]], Length@class1], #2}], PlotStyle->pointstyle] [[1]]`.  Then specify the list of colors , for example, `cols= ColorData["Rainbow"]/@RandomReal[1, Length@data];` and  ...

Comment: ... use `BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MedianMarker", 1, 
   Directive[Thickness[.007], White]}}, ImageSize -> 700, 
 ChartStyle -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  densityCalloutWhiskerF[][data, class2, .3, .7, .5, 
   PointSize[Large], Directive[PointSize[.007], cols]]]`.  If your `originaldata` is a list of pairs, you need to set `data=originaldata[[All,1]]` , and, perhaps, `cols= ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale@#]&/@originaldata[[All,2]]`.